# Does $f^m\in k[x_{t+1},...,x_n]$ imply $f \in k[x_{t+1},...,x_n]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

The context in which I have come up with this question is when trying to prove the relation between projection of varieties and elimination of variables in algebraic geometry.

I one step of my proof I use the fact that if a power of a polynomial, $f^m$, belongs to the polynomial ring $k[x_{t+1},...,x_n]$, then the polynomial $f$ must also belong to this polynomial ring. At first I thought this was obvious, but I am not sure whether it is true after thinking more about it. Is there any counterexample in which some variable which "appears" in the expression of $f$ "disappears " when doing some power of the polynomial? In case it were true, some hint of how to go about proving this would be helpful.

Also, I am assuming $k$ is an algebraically closed field, in case that is important.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose for contradiction, that $f$ has a non-zero component on a variable $x_i \in \{x_1, \dots, x_t\}$ and consider the coefficient associated to the highest degree in $x_i$. Can this coefficient disappear when you raise $f$ at power $m$ knowing that $k$ is a field of characteristic zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true. Note that naturally $k[x_1,...,x_n]\cong k[x_2,...,x_n][x_1]$. So you can view $f$ as a polynomial in the variable $x_1$ over the integral domain $k[x_2,...,x_n]$. Then:

$\deg_{x_1}(f^m)=m\cdot\deg_{x_1}(f)$

So if $x_1$ appeared in $f$, it will not disappear in $f^m$.